# orderby Clause in linq

Tags: linq

I have this linq syntax that I would like to order by the results based on LocalDateTime field

```
from d in Devices

where d.Name=="switch01"


select new {d.deviceId, Performance=d.Performance.system.io}
```

LocalDatetime is a property of io. I can get the results but they are not ordered by date and time.

LocalDateTime is type DateTime here is the output:

```
LocalDateTime   Value
3/9/2012 1:05   5000.7
3/9/2012 1:15   4775.6
3/9/2012 1:35   3743.3
3/9/2012 9:05   656.3
3/9/2012 7:45   670.4
3/9/2012 10:15  621.7
3/9/2012 7:15   665.4
3/9/2012 7:10   603.9
```

Comment: Are we talking in-memory Linq or are we talking Linq against the database? (Linq2NHibernate/Linq2SQL/Linq2EF...)?

Answer (score 3):

```
from d in Devices

where d.Name=="switch01"

orderby d.Performance.system.io.LocalDatetime 

select new {d.deviceId, Performance=d.Performance.system.io}
```

Comment: @mikesmith, Show your inputs and outputs and say why you think this not work? I there any exception or unwanted result? If is so, Show us. Also what is type of your `LocalDateTime`?